# Is there any way to integrate spring security authentication/authorization feature in to an angular js application?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-security

We have done a single page application using angular js which uses angular routing for redirection.

Spring-security xml

```
 <http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_USER" /> 

    <form-login 
        login-page="/rest/testing/login" 
        authentication-failure-url="/rest/testing/login?error" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/rest/testing/login"  />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Angular Routing:

```
XmlView.config(function($routeProvider)
   {$routeProvider

    // route for the home page
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'transform.jsp',
        controller : 'ViewController'
    })

    // route for the search page
    .when('/search', {
        templateUrl : 'search.jsp',
        controller : 'SearchController'
    })

    // route for the about page
    .when('/admin', {
        templateUrl : 'audits.jsp',
        controller : 'AuditController'
    })

    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl : 'login.jsp',

    })
```

The problem which i face on spring security integration is, intercept url's specified in spring security is not working. Please give a solution.

Comment: Make sure that the pages accessed are protected by the filter or at least the url that is being requested. I suspect that isn't the case here and that the tsp files are loaded from the root of the application instead of the `/admin` path.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined the Spring Security filter in `web.xml`?

```
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        version="2.5">

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <!-- Spring context files to be loaded -->
        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                <!-- Parent context -->
                /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml,
                /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
            </param-value>
        </context-param>

        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

        <!-- filter declaration for Spring Security -->
        <filter>
          <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
          <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
          <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
          <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

BTW, I see that you have just started with your project since you are hardcoding the user info there.

If you want to avoid building a whole User-management layer from scratch you could consider [Stormpath](http://stormpath.com).

[Among many features](https://stormpath.com/resources/datasheet/), we provide a [Spring Security Plugin](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-spring-security) that uses Stormpath as the authentication and authorization provider.

You can take a look at our [Spring Security Web Example](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-spring-security-example/tree/master).

The instructions to get the sample app running are detailed here: https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-spring-security-example/blob/master/README.md

You can see the [Plugin wiki](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-spring-security/wiki) for mode details.

With our Plugin you will get out of the box:

1. User authentication against Stormpath
2. Account's groups will translate to Spring Security's Granted Authorities for Authorization
3. Group's and Account's Custom Data will translate to Spring Security's Permissions for Authorization

We also support [AngularJS](https://docs.stormpath.com/home/).

Disclaimer, I am active Stormpath contributor.